# If column's items doesn't equal another column's items, append to a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Let's say I have a CSV `invites.csv`:

```
Email Invite                    Email Denied                                                                                       
batman@email.com                batman@email.com                       
poisonivy@email.com             catgirl@email.com             
superman@email.com              supergirl@email.com           
catgirl@email.com                           
joker@email.com                             
supergirl@email.com
```

I want to compare both columns and have a new column made, `Emails Left`, with just the emails that are not in the `Email Denied` column. An output like this:

```
Email Invite                    Email Denied               Emails Left                                                                                 
batman@email.com                batman@email.com           poisonivy@email.com               
poisonivy@email.com             catgirl@email.com          superman@email.com   
superman@email.com              supergirl@email.com        joker@email.com   
catgirl@email.com                                          flash@email.com
joker@email.com                             
supergirl@email.com
flash@email.com
```

This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

Dir='invites.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(Dir)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

a = len(df['Email invite'])
aList = []

for i in range(a):
    if df['Email invite'][i] != df['Email Denied'][i]:
        aList.append(df['Email Invite'][i])  

#place list as third column df['Emails Left']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had to make the column rows match each other first before doing the IF statement.

```
df = pd.read_csv(Dir)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df = pd.merge(df[["Email Invite"]],
              df[['Email Denied']],
              left_on='Email Invite',
              right_on='Email Denied',
              how='left')
```

This then leaves the DataFrame looking like this:

```
Email Invite                    Email Denied                                                                                       
batman@email.com                batman@email.com                       
poisonivy@email.com                          
superman@email.com                         
catgirl@email.com               catgirl@email.com             
joker@email.com                             
supergirl@email.com             supergirl@email.com
```

I continue to my FOR loop and IF statement:

```
a = len(df['Email invite'])
aList = []

for i in range(a):
    if df['Email invite'][i] != df['Email Denied'][i]:
        aList.append(df['Email Invite'][i])  

df['Emails Left'] = pd.Series(aList)
```

Now I have my extra column:

```
Email Invite                  Email Denied           Emails Left                                                                                      
batman@email.com              batman@email.com       poisonivy@email.com                
poisonivy@email.com                                  superman@email.com  
superman@email.com                                   joker@email.com
catgirl@email.com             catgirl@email.com              
joker@email.com                             
supergirl@email.com           supergirl@email.com
```

And I can now transfer it to a new CSV.

```
df.to_csv("NewInvite.csv", index=False)
```

Now the program is running good.

Answer (score -1):

It is not recommended to use dataframes with columns of different lengths. You have to pad out remaining elements with NaN or ' ' or something to make them equal lengths. List would work better here:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Email Invite': ['batman@email.com', 'poisonivy@email.com', 'superman@email.com','catgirl@email.com' ,'joker@email.com' ,'supergirl@email.com'], 'Email Denied': ['batman@email.com', 'catgirl@email.com' ,'supergirl@email.com', '','','']})


email_invited = list(df['Email Invite'])
email_denied = list(df[df['Email Denied']!='']['Email Denied'])

email_left = [email for email in email_invited if email not in email_denied]
print(email_left)
```